# Dynamic DIV height

Tags: css

In the HEAD of the page I have

```
<style type="text/css">
    html {
        overflow: hidden
    }
    html, body, #centralDIvision {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 1100px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    #centralDivision {
        float: left;
    }
    #outer {
        display: table;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%
    }
</style>
```

But instead of having the height of the centralDivision div equal to 400px, I'd like it to be 75% of the browser's current screen size. Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: please show the HTML. the DOM structure is essential here.

Comment: what have you tried?  Also is it not just `height:75%` on the `#centralDivision` rule?

Answer (score 2):

just for diversity, another approach, using absolute positioning:

```css
#parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.5%;
    bottom: 12.5%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}​
```

and a [working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/bzMMz/), of course.

Comment: dude those CSS arrow heads are pro

Comment: thanks, there are quite a few interesting references, among them [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/), [CSS zen garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/), and of course, the [CSS home page on W3C](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/). if you liked those arrows, there are also similar techniques for creating [pure CSS speech bubbles](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/55yqG/). yup, CSS is quite the sh** :)

Answer (score 1):

`#centralDIvision { height: 75%; }` will get you pretty close, if the #centralDIvision element is a direct descendent of the body.  (When height is specified in %, it's based on the parent's height.)

Comment: +1 - a workaround if it's not the direct descendant will be to use 75% on the ultimate owner container and then use 100% for all children; or equally 100% on the owner container and 75% just for #centralDivision; depending on what's required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing this

```
height: 400px;
```

with this?

```
height: 75%;
```